# Primefaces dialog framework not working while using ajax listener

Tags: ajax, primefaces, dialog, jsf-2.2, dialog-framework

I'm trying to open dialog using Primefaces 4 dialog framework,

```
public void openDialog(String viewName) {
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(viewName);
}
```

This works:

```
<p:commandButton value="Click" action="#{impaktDialogBean.openDialog('/popup/test2')}"/>
```

This doesn't:

```
<p:commandButton value="Click">     
  <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{impaktDialogBean.openDialog('/popup/test2')}" ></p:ajax>
</p:commandButton>
```

So, Primefaces dialog framework only works with action & actionListener?????

I'm using:

- Primefaces 4
- Tomcat 7
- JSF 2.2.6 Mojarra

Thanks.

Comment: p:commandButton has ajax="true" by default, why do you want to invoke p:ajax, did you tried making ajax="false".

Comment: Yes I know ,but what if i want to open dialog on events where action can't be fired like data table row select?????...ajax=false doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
public void openDialog(String someView) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(someView);
}
```

So when you do this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton id="button" value="Click" actionListener="#{bean.openDialog('someView')}" />
</h:form>
```

You recieve this in your Ajax response:

```
PrimeFaces.openDialog({
    url:'/some/address/view.xhtml',
    pfdlgcid:'cf8e7955-a6cf-4dd8-9a07-55cd29696a64',
    sourceComponentId:'form:button',
    sourceWidget:PF('widget_form_button'),
    options:{}});
```

So, you can try this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton id="button" value="Click" onclick="PrimeFaces.openDialog({
        url:'/some/address/view.xhtml',
        pfdlgcid:'cf8e7955-a6cf-4dd8-9a07-55cd29696a64',
        sourceComponentId:'form:button',
        sourceWidget:PF('widget_form_button'),
        options:{}});" />
</h:form>
```

You can even use the return value:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

    <p:commandButton id="button" value="Click" onclick="PrimeFaces.openDialog({
        url:'/some/address/view.xhtml',
        pfdlgcid:'cf8e7955-a6cf-4dd8-9a07-55cd29696a64',
        sourceComponentId:'form:button',
        sourceWidget:PF('widget_form_button'),
        options:{}});">

        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{bean.returnedValue}" update="growl" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The AJAX is just to turn the outcome to the destination url. If you already have the destination url, you dont need to do it. In my basic tests this works well, exactly like the original, except that you must pass the destination address in the 'url' field, not the outcome.

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: Yeah, it works, you can put it on the `oncomplete` ajax attrib and the dialog gets fired. But it's safe to hardcode the `pfdlgcid`?? Its natural behaviour seems to change randomly on every call.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I've found is to fire up the button via javascript.

The button that opens the dialog (maybe hidden):

```
<p:commandButton id="myButton" action="#{bean.openMyDialog}" style="display:none" />
```

The ajax event that 'clicks' the button:

```
<p:ajax ... oncomplete=" $('#myButton').click() " />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked long time ago but for future times...

What about a `<p:remoteCommand>` ?

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteCmd" update="anything" actionListener="#{impaktDialogBean.openDialog('/popup/test2')}" />

<p:commandButton value="Click" update="anything" onclick="remoteCmd()" >
```

Different approach to achieve a javascript call to your bean.